# Create query that calculates the due dates using Dlookup

Tags: vba, ms-access, dlookup

I am trying to use a module as of of my fields for a query that looks up the frequencies of a training and how long until it is due for a certain employee. I have a table which holds all the employee info (Workday_Excel_Update) as well as the training course number, when he was enrolled and if it was completed. I also have a second table with all the training numbers (CourseNumbers), the month-day when the training should be complete and the frequency in months.

I wrote the code in the module to use as field but I keep getting the following error:

> "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error:
> 'Microsoft Access cannot find the name 'CourseNum' you entered in the
> expression'"

the reason for the dlookup is to find the corresponding date and frequency for the course number.

the CourseNumbers table has the following fields:
-CourseNumber
-CourseName
-Frequency (which is the month-day)
-Months (The frequency in months until the training is required again)

If anyone can tell me why and if you have a solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Image of my query with the module

[image]

```
Function getDueDate(CourseNum As String)


Dim yearCounter As Integer
Dim yearStart As Date
Dim yearNow As Integer
Dim monthFreq As Integer
Dim daysDue As Integer

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Months]", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = CourseNum")) Then

 
monthFreq = DLookup("[Months]", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = CourseNum")

yearStart = DLookup("[Frequency]", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = CourseNum")

yearCounter = Year(yearStart)

yearNow = Year(Date)

While yearCounter <= yearNow
    
    yearStart = DateAdd("m", monthFreq, yearStart)
    
    yearCounter = yearCounter + (monthFreq / 12)
    
Wend

daysDue = DateDiff("d", Date, yearStart)

Else

daysDue = 0

End If


getDueDate = daysDue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`CourseNum` is a variable. You do not include variables inside of quotes.

You also do not specify if the ***field*** `CourseNumber` is a text field or a numeric field, so depending on that, you want to:

Replace `"CourseNumber = CourseNum"` (in all 3 places):

If it's a number field, replace it with:

```
"CourseNumber = " & CourseNum
```

If it's text field, replace it with:

```
"CourseNumber = '" & CourseNum & "'"
```

<sub>Unrelated: If your field is text, then you should probably not name it something that has the word "number" in it.</sub>